# Tone of the below mentioned phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I received this in reply and I do not get it whether he is being bossy, rude, neutral, jerk or normal or what??????

> Exactly you will need physically pull it out and put it in an excel sheet… I have give you the heads I need it in its going to hard manual work

What does he mean by 'give the heads'? Is there any phrase "give the heads up"?

Comment: I think when he says 'heads' he means 'headings' but this could really use more context.  Also, is he typing this on a phone?

Comment: i do not know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the second sentence rendered into normal English would be "I have given you the headers that I need; it's going to be hard manual work".

As such, the statement is emotionally neutral. The first sentence is also neutral: the sender is telling you what needs to be done in a straight-forward manner.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted sentence is badly formed; it seems that the writer is either in a haste or isn't very articulate in English, or both.

Extracting the tone of a written message can be challenging even when it's well-written. With this message, you can only guess. As you see in previous answers, different people make different guesses...

In my opinion, interpreting this message as "bossy", "rude", or "jerk" might be too judgemental. Without previous experience with this person, I would probably treat him as "presumed innocenct". I can change your mind later if I get more evidence...

Anyway, what he wants you to do seems quite clear.